# How can I upload an image with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to upload an image with AJAX. When I try like this, nothing happens. AJAX does not call `H_FileUpload.php`. But the `$("#in_profile_img")` part does work. Only the AJAX call does not work. Why doesn't it work?

HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu fm-menu" role="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$.change_profile_img()">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Change
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</a></li>
</ul>
<form id="form_profile_image" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="profile_img" id="in_profile_img" style="display:none;" />
</form><!-- profile image form -->
```

JavaScript:

```
$.change_profile_img = function() {
    $("#in_profile_img").click();
}

$("#in_profile_img").on('change', (function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        url : "./handlers/H_FileUpload.php",
        type : "POST", 
        data : formData,
        cache : false,
        contentType : false,
        processType : false,
        success : function(data) {
            alert("Success");
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}));
```

PHP (H_FileUpload.php):

```
<?php
$name = $_FILES["profile_img"]["name"];
$result["ok"] = $name;

echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Comment: im not sure why you are having `click()` on the function and your event is `change()`?

Comment: yes, click event for open the directory and change event for choose image and that is not the question or answer

Comment: I recommend having an upload button there after choosing an image. Why? because if you keep on changing picture then firing an ajax to upload an image image to your server, that is not a good thing. You need to consider also, when fired an ajax with a large filesize then suddenly user change the image. What do you think will happen? I'm pretty sure you didn't include that scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
var formData = new FormData(this);
```

to

```
var formData = new FormData($('#form_profile_image')[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
var formData = new FormData($(this)); //$(this) is an object
```

Or you can do add more parameter:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

Please see: [How to use FormData for ajax file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload)

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors,

1. Select form when using `FormData` object.
2. Specify `enctype`.
3. use `processData` not processType.

try this

```
    $("#in_profile_img").on('change', function(e){

        e.preventDefault;

        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("form_profile_image"));

        $.ajax({
            url : "./handlers/H_FileUpload.php",
            type : "POST", 
            data : formData,
            cache : false,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            contentType : false,
            processData : false,
            success : function(data) {
                alert("Success");
                alert(data);
            }
        });

    });
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Try this in your ajax

```
var data = new FormData($('#posting_comment')[0]);
    $.ajax({
                   type:"POST",
                   url:"handlers/H_FileUpload.php",
                   data:data,
                   mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                   success:function(data)
                  {
                        //alert(data);
                          $(".image").html(data);
                   }
           });
```

IN your php file

```
$attachment_file=$_FILES["profile_img"];
$output_dir = "upload/";
$fileName = $_FILES["profile_img"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profile_img"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName);
//echo "File uploaded successfully";
```

For more read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-upload-file-using-php-and-ajax-beginner-guide/

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery which would significantly simplify the task.
Import jquery: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js

```
var formData = $("#in_profile_img");
$.post('./handlers/H_FileUpload.php',{data:formData},function(e){
    alert("success");
    alert(e);
});
```